# R Multiple T-test: Grouping factor must have 2 variables

Tags: r, t-test

I'm trying to compare a control group with an experimental group on a range of variable to show that they are similar (baseline).

I thus need to do multiple t-test (unpaired/ Welch t-test). My data is in a long format with the first variable called "Group" with either a number 1 or a number 2. There are some missing values in some of my other variables but it's pretty random.

So when I run t-test manually using this line of code:

```
t.test(variable_1 ~ Group,df)
```

it works.

I then tried to do it all at once using this line of code:

```
 sapply(df[,2:71], function(i) t.test(i ~ df$Group)$p.value)
```

But I get the following error:

> grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

Could anyone help?

Here is what the structure looks like

```
structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), EM_Accuracy_Time_Airport = c(3, 3, 0, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1), EM_Accuracy_Place_Airport = c(2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), EM_Accuracy_Expl_Airport = c(2, 
2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1), EM_Accuracy_Death_Airport = c(0, 
2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), EM_Accuracy_Time_Metro = c(3, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3), EM_Accuracy_Death_Metro = c(3, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), EM_Accuracy_PC_Time_Airpot = c(100, 
100, 0, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 
66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 100, 100, 
66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 
100, 33.3333333333333, 100, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333
), EM_Accuracy_PC_Place_Airport = c(100, 100, 50, 100, 50, 100, 
100, 50, 50, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50), 
    EM_Accuracy_PC_Expl_Airport = c(100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 
    100, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 50, 0, 100, 100, 
    50), EM_Accuracy_PC_Death_Airport = c(0, 66.6666666666667, 
    0, 0, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 66.6666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0), EM_Accuracy_PC_Time_Metro = c(100, 
    33.3333333333333, 0, 0, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
    0, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
    33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 100, 
    33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 
    100, 100), EM_Accuracy_PC_Death_Metro = c(100, 0, 33.3333333333333, 
    0, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 
    33.3333333333333, 0, 100, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
    33.3333333333333, 0, 0), EM_ACCURACY_PC = c(83.3333333333333, 
    66.6666666666667, 30.5555555555556, 22.2222222222222, 47.2222222222222, 
    66.6666666666666, 44.4444444444444, 27.7777777777778, 36.1111111111111, 
    72.2222222222222, 38.8888888888889, 55.5555555555555, 66.6666666666666, 
    27.7777777777778, 44.4444444444444, 52.7777777777778, 55.5555555555556, 
    52.7777777777778, 47.2222222222222, 38.8888888888889), EM_Certainty_Time_Airport = c(3, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2), 
    EM_Certainty__Place_Airport = c(3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3), EM_Certainty__Expl_Airport = c(4, 
    2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
    EM_Certainty__Death_Airport = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
    2, 3, NA, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4), EM_Certainty__Time_Metro = c(3, 
    3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2), 
    EM_Certainty__Death_Metro = c(2, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, NA, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4), EM_CERTAINTY = c(2.66666666666667, 
    2, 1.6, 1.2, 2, 1.83333333333333, 2.16666666666667, 1, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.83333333333333, 2.75, 2.83333333333333, 2.5, 1.83333333333333, 
    2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 1.83333333333333, 
    2.16666666666667, 3), EM_CONFIDENCE = c(5, 5, 1, 2, 2, 4, 
    5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2), FBM_CONFIDENCE = c(4, 
    6, 7, 7, 5, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6), 
    FBM_Vividness_Time = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3), FBM_Vividness_How = c(4, 4, 2, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), FBM_Vividness_Where = c(4, 
    4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
    FBM_Vividness_WithWhom = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), FBM_Vividness_WereDoing = c(4, 
    4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
    FBM_Vividness_Did_After = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
    1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4), FBM_VIVIDNESS = c(3.83333333333333, 
    3.83333333333333, 2, 4, 3.16666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    4, 3.83333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4, 2.33333333333333, 
    3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 3.5, 4, 3.83333333333333
    ), FBM_Details_NB_T2 = c(3, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 5), P_Novelty_5 = c(5, 6.2, 6.5, 
    5.6, 4.8, 5.4, 4, 4.2, 4.4, 5.8, 3.4, 5.8, 6, 5.8, 3.8, 6.4, 
    6.8, 6.6, 7, 3), P_Suprise_emotion = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 
    1, 7, 1, 5, 4, 5, 7, 7, 6, 4, 7, 7, 2, 5), P_Surprise_Expected = c(1, 
    3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, 2, 2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4), 
    P_Surprise_Unbelievable = c(5, 4, 1, 6, 4, 4, 2, 7, 1, 4, 
    1, 6, 7, 7, 6, 3, 7, 7, 5, 3), `P_Consequence-Importance_5` = c(5.6, 
    4.8, 3.4, 5, 4.8, 4, 5, 5.4, 3, 5.2, 6.8, 5.4, 4, 4.4, 6, 
    3.8, 4, 4.8, 5, 5.2), P_Emotional_Intensity_4 = c(5.25, 5.75, 
    3, 4.75, 4.75, 6, 4, 5.25, 2.5, 5.5, 7, 6.5, 5.75, 6.75, 
    6.75, 6, 6.25, 6, 5, 2.5), P_Social_Sharing_6 = c(3.66666666666667, 
    3.83333333333333, 3.4, 3.16666666666667, 3, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.8, 3.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.33333333333333, 4, 3.16666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
    4, NA, NA), P_Media_3 = c(4.66666666666667, 4, 3, 2.66666666666667, 
    2.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 3, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 5, 
    4.33333333333333, 5, 4, 2, 3, 3.33333333333333, 2, 1.66666666666667
    ), P_Ruminations = c(3, NA, 3, 2, 4, NA, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 
    2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3), P_Novelty_Common_rev = c(6, 7, 7, 
    7, 4, 6, 4, 7, 2, 6, 3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 3), P_Novelty_Unusual = c(2, 
    5, 7, 7, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 2), 
    P_Novelty_Special = c(6, 6, NA, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 
    6, 7, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 3), P_Novelty_Singular = c(4, 6, 5, 
    1, 5, 5, 4, 1, 3, 6, 5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 7, 7, 6, 7, 2), P_Novelty_Ordinary_rev = c(7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5), 
    P_Consequence = c(6, 7, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 
    2, 6, 6, 1, 4, 6, 3), P_Importance_self = c(4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
    3, 5, 6, 1, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3), `P_Importance_friends&family` = c(4, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 5, 6, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 5, 10), 
    P_Importance_Belgium = c(7, 5, 3, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 7, 
    7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6), P_Importance_International = c(7, 
    5, 3, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 7, 5, 4, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4), 
    P_Emotional_Intensity_Upset = c(4, 5, NA, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 
    2, 5, 7, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 3), P_Emotional_Intensity_Indiferent_rev = c(7, 
    7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 4, 6, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, NA, 4), 
    P_Emotional_Intensity_Affected = c(6, 6, 3, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 
    2, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, 2), P_Emotional_Intensity_Shaken = c(4, 
    5, 1, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 1), 
    P_Rehearsal_Media_TV = c(5, 3, NA, 3, 2, 3, NA, 1, 1, 4, 
    3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2), P_Rehearsal_Media_Internet = c(4, 
    4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1), 
    P_Rehearsal_Media_Social_Networks = c(5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2), P_Social_Sharing_How_Often = c(4, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, NA), 
    P_Social_Sharing_With_How_Many_People = c(5, 4, NA, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, NA), PK_Shops_YN = c(0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
    PK_Comic = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), PK_Hotel = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PK_Decoration_Maelbeek = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
    PK_Stations_before_after_Maelbeek = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0), PK_TOTAL_PC = c(0, 
    50, 0, 40, 40, 40, 20, 0, 10, 60, 20, 40, 90, 70, 20, 0, 
    30, 20, 70, 40), SI_Attachment_BXL = c(6, 4, 1, 4, 2, 5, 
    1, 6, 5, 4, 2, 6, 6, 7, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 4), SI_Pride_BXL = c(1, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 3), 
    SI_Attachment_Belgium = c(7, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 7, 6, 4, 2), SI_Pride_Belgium = c(7, 2, 6, 
    4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 6, 2, 2), SI_Attachment_EU = c(6, 
    4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 1, 6, 7, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 2, 6), 
    SI_Pride_EU = c(7, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 6, 7, 7, 
    4, 3, 6, 6, 2, 4)), .Names = c("Group", "EM_Accuracy_Time_Airport", 
"EM_Accuracy_Place_Airport", "EM_Accuracy_Expl_Airport", "EM_Accuracy_Death_Airport", 
"EM_Accuracy_Time_Metro", "EM_Accuracy_Death_Metro", "EM_Accuracy_PC_Time_Airpot", 
"EM_Accuracy_PC_Place_Airport", "EM_Accuracy_PC_Expl_Airport", 
"EM_Accuracy_PC_Death_Airport", "EM_Accuracy_PC_Time_Metro", 
"EM_Accuracy_PC_Death_Metro", "EM_ACCURACY_PC", "EM_Certainty_Time_Airport", 
"EM_Certainty__Place_Airport", "EM_Certainty__Expl_Airport", 
"EM_Certainty__Death_Airport", "EM_Certainty__Time_Metro", "EM_Certainty__Death_Metro", 
"EM_CERTAINTY", "EM_CONFIDENCE", "FBM_CONFIDENCE", "FBM_Vividness_Time", 
"FBM_Vividness_How", "FBM_Vividness_Where", "FBM_Vividness_WithWhom", 
"FBM_Vividness_WereDoing", "FBM_Vividness_Did_After", "FBM_VIVIDNESS", 
"FBM_Details_NB_T2", "P_Novelty_5", "P_Suprise_emotion", "P_Surprise_Expected", 
"P_Surprise_Unbelievable", "P_Consequence-Importance_5", "P_Emotional_Intensity_4", 
"P_Social_Sharing_6", "P_Media_3", "P_Ruminations", "P_Novelty_Common_rev", 
"P_Novelty_Unusual", "P_Novelty_Special", "P_Novelty_Singular", 
"P_Novelty_Ordinary_rev", "P_Consequence", "P_Importance_self", 
"P_Importance_friends&family", "P_Importance_Belgium", "P_Importance_International", 
"P_Emotional_Intensity_Upset", "P_Emotional_Intensity_Indiferent_rev", 
"P_Emotional_Intensity_Affected", "P_Emotional_Intensity_Shaken", 
"P_Rehearsal_Media_TV", "P_Rehearsal_Media_Internet", "P_Rehearsal_Media_Social_Networks", 
"P_Social_Sharing_How_Often", "P_Social_Sharing_With_How_Many_People", 
"PK_Shops_YN", "PK_Comic", "PK_Hotel", "PK_Decoration_Maelbeek", 
"PK_Stations_before_after_Maelbeek", "PK_TOTAL_PC", "SI_Attachment_BXL", 
"SI_Pride_BXL", "SI_Attachment_Belgium", "SI_Pride_Belgium", 
"SI_Attachment_EU", "SI_Pride_EU"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your data with `dput(head(df,n))`. Choose n as may be sufficient for reproducibility.

Comment: Googling your error message leads me to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421475/basic-t-test-grouping-factor-must-have-exactly-2-levels where it suggests to do `t.test(i, df$Group)$p.value`. Can you try that in your `sapply` call ?

Comment: @NelsonGon : I have added the structure.

Comment: @Ronak Shah: using a comma does a different type of test, which compares two variables (the one before the comma with the one after the comma). It works for a wide format, but I'm using a long format with a grouping variable

Comment: What is `variable_1`?

Comment: Any of the variable after "Group". So for example: it works fine if I run t.test(EM_Accuracy_Place_Airport ~ Group,df)

Comment: Some of the columns have more than two levels (eg, `EM_Accuracy_Time_Airport = c(3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1)`). You could consider formulating this problem as a linear regression rather than a simple t-test.

Comment: There could be many reasons why your code breaks. One of them is because in one of the variables you have only `NA`s associated with one level of your grouping variable. Check this: `t.test(df$P_Social_Sharing_6 ~ df$Group)`

Comment: @Aocall: that shouldn't be an issue as Group is my IV and all the others are DV. So I want to compare Group 1 with Group 2 for all the other variables.

Comment: @AntoniosK! How did I miss that one! Yes, thanks, I've added the missing values and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The error you get means that there's a problem in your dataset, with at least one of your variables.

Here's a process to help you spot problematic variables:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%                   # for each group value
  summarise_all(~sum(!is.na(.))) %>%    # count non NA values for each variable
  gather(var,value,-Group) %>%          # reshape
  spread(Group, value, sep = "_") %>%   # reshape
  filter(Group_2 < 2)                   # get problematic variables

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   var                                   Group_1 Group_2
#   <chr>                                   <int>   <int>
# 1 P_Emotional_Intensity_Affected             18       1
# 2 P_Emotional_Intensity_Indiferent_rev       18       1
# 3 P_Social_Sharing_6                         18       0
# 4 P_Social_Sharing_How_Often                 18       1
# 5 P_Social_Sharing_With_How_Many_People      17       1
```

0 counts will throw an error about needing two levels in your grouping variables.

1 count will throw an error about needing more observations in one of your groups.

After spotting those you have to treat them accordingly and then your original `t.test` code should work.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that in the future!

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was just missing data in one variable.

However, if you are looking at doing multiple T-test in a long format: this line of code works:

> sapply(df[,2:71], function(i) t.test(i ~ df$Group)$p.value)