# "Error in t.test.formula (ttResults <- t.test(airline$favorite_count ~ airline$screen_name) : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

Tags: r

My code is `ttResults <- t.test(airline$favorite_count ~ airline$screen_name)`. It's for a data frame I have. The favorites is my numerical `var` and screen name is my categorical var. I've done the same test with similar code before and it worked.

I'm pretty new to R. I'm not sure how to check how many levels I have or recode to adjust the levels.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421475/basic-t-test-grouping-factor-must-have-exactly-2-levels

Comment: You should do `t.test(favorite_count~screen_name, data=airline)`. Seems that the screen name does not have 2 categories. Hence you cannot do a t.test. probably you should consider an anova

Comment: What does `nlevels(airline$screen_name)` return? Or if it's not a factor, `length(unique(airline$screen_name))` will tell you the number of groups you have. A t-test only works with two groups so it doesn't sound like it's the right test for your data. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.